# How to save a resultSet in 2 tables with relationships and show it in table view with headers

Tags: ios, mysql, json, swift, fmdb

I need to save my json in SQL database and show it in table view with headers. For example, own app 'Contacts' in iPhone. This has a list of contacts sorted by symbol in header.

this is my json

[image]

I use FMDB in swift 2. Anybody help.